# Message Box to Show Array and Text

Tags: c#, arrays, text, message

What I am trying to achieve is for the program to record whats in Textbox1 and spit it back and say welcome "name". This is the code I have currently got. thank you!

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = textBox1.Text;

        if (textBox1.Text == "Ryan" && textBox2.Text == "password")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome" + name);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is variable "name"?

Comment: Your string concatenation is off a bit -- try string.Format("Welcome {0}", name);

Comment: this doesn't even compile

Comment: && isn't a concatenation operator. It's the AND operator. Change && to +

Comment: and where is the problem ? Is there an error message or something like that ?

Comment: @Mr.Beckett - you've edited the original code and now masked where the fault was! Original code had "MessageBox.Show("Welcome" & name)", your update means that any one else who sees it won't understand where the problem is!

Comment: @DaveRook I edited the code to show the fixed result. Thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot concatenate with && -- use string.Format instead:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Welcome {0}", name));
```

With your edited code, you cannot use name in this event -- you'd need to use textBox1.Text.  Or you can define your name variable as global.  Depends on your needs.

Comment: This works also! I do not understand this part. string.Format("Welcome {0}",

What is the {0} about ?

Comment: @Mr.Beckett - Do some research on string.Format and read the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.100).aspx you could also use `MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + name);` if you wanted.

Comment: @Mr.Beckett -- it's a placeholder for the next argument, in this case, name.  string.Format can take in any number of args {0} {1} {2} and replace those after the comma -- easier to read in my opinion.  string.format("{0} {1}", "Best", "Regards");

Comment: @sgeddes What do the numbers stand for ? eg. {0}, {1}

Comment: @Mr.Beckett -- place holders for the values you're trying to concatenate -- give it a try :)  In my above comment, {0} = "Best" and {1} = "Regards" -- together, "Best Regards"!

Comment: @sgeddes I Understand the numbers now thanks!. One more question. It isn't happy with string.format( it has a red underline under the format

Comment: @Mr.Beckett -- it's case sensitive -- use string.Format with a capital F.  Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @sgeddes - I love this website! Trying to self teach myself coding languages for about a year now this will help me learn alot faster! thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `+` to `concatenate` strings and use `textBox1.Text` for name as you do not have `name` variable defined.

```
 MessageBox.Show("Welcome" + textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `&&` (and operator) for `+` in the Messagebox line.

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageBox.Show("Welcome" + name);  // suppose "name" is the string you want to aggregate.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do this?:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (textBox1.Text == "Ryan" && textBox2.Text == "password")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome" + textBox1.Text);            

    }
}
```

> TextBox1.Text and TextBox2.Text contains the value of the names.

Comment: Thank you very much this works!. Im gonna try and achieve with an Array aswell.

Answer (score 0):

In c# you have to use + for concatenation instead of &&

```
MessageBox.Show("Welcome" && name);
```

should be

```
MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would update to

```
 MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + name);
```

Please note I've included a space after the "welcome", otherwise it will read WelcomeRyan instead of Welcome Ryan

Comment: Thank you. I worked that out myself. at least I can do that haha

Comment: I would give it a useful answer but I'm only new to this and dont have enough rep.

Answer (score -1):

I assume the "name" you want to output is the what is in the .Text property of textBox1 - then you want to change your code like:

```
    if (textBox1.Text == "Ryan" && textBox2.Text == "password")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome" + textBox1.Text);
    }
```